# CSS box-shadow doesn't work

Tags: css

Why doesn't this CSS box shadow work?

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://placecage.com/90/90" />
```

**CSS**

```
IMG {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;    
}
```

I've tried it in all browsers. I've tried it in jsFiddle. I've tried different values. I've tried different ways to express the colour. I've tried many browsers.

Thanks

Comment: You have an image in your HTML and you are trying to target a hyperlink element? Can you edit your question to provide the HTML and CSS you are using?

Comment: your inset box shadow will be drawn under the image , unless you have a translucide image you won't see much. you need a wrapper, <img> doesn't take pseudo-elements :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inset` box shadows do **not** work on image elements.

One way you can achieve this is by having another div overlapping the image element

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/STcTN/2/

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/90/90" />    
</div>


.img-container{
    width: 90px; height: 90px;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container:after{
    content: '';
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 7px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 7px #000000;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 7px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 7px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 7px #000000;    
}
```

Comment: After spending too long on this, I just found another SO answer saying the same thing. So, that's inset box shadow use-case #1 out the window. I love CSS.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for the complete answer. I can't wrap the image without breaking all the elastic sizing stuff. I just have neither the time or patience for CSS.

Comment: Do you I did manage to put a wrapper DIV around the image and with a width of 80% the flexible layout still works (its just random). Anyway, the box shadow still doesn't work.

Comment: What's with the `after` pseudo selector? Will a box shadow applied on the container itself not work??

Comment: @LukePuplett nope, because the image is in the box so the box is under the image

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to contain your image and apply the box-shadow to that, or if possible have the image applied as a background to the container.

HTML

```
<div class="as-img">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/90/90" />
</div>

<div class="as-background"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 108px 7px #000000;    
}

img{

    opacity:0.5;
}

div.as-background{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    background:url('http://placecage.com/90/90') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steakpi/T7haL/)

You can see that the inset box shadow favors the background image, as you have to reduce opacity to see it directly behind the . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSS3 inset box shadows on images as described in [this article](http://designbystevie.com/2011/03/applying-css3-inset-box-shadows-to-images/)

The best way to achieve this goal is to add an absolute position element, an anchor or div, over the images.